# showing more text in activity chooser menu title

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

Generally it only shows two lines of text in the Activity Chooser menu, rest is shown as "some text...". How to show 4-5 lines of text in the title?

[image: more text in the title]

.

.

Comment: Could you supply a screenshot to explain what you are talking about?

Comment: You can try the `\n` trick mentioned by @tinny_bug, but you should *not* be putting "4-5 lines" there. For example, on the device you are using for that screenshot, "4-5 lines" means there would be no room for any entries in the list.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to because I will only show two app in that list. Dialer & skype.

Answer (score 0):

you really want to show more lines. when you set the message to the textview ,you can try like 
this:
    someText.setText("中华人民共和国.\n united states \n enourpe \n");
it should auto change line like you doing in the J2EE application